# Libgdx box2d - what is the best approach to spawn an actor on a stage dynamically?

Tags: java, libgdx, platformer

I'm currently building a 2d sprite infinite runner game, but everytime I spawn new enemy(actor) and platform, I noticed that there's a delay on it. Any idea of what would cause this behavior? I'm using textureAtlas to animate each enemy, and I used the same approach of Drops game in LibGdx.

Here's my code on the stage class

```
private void update(Body body) {     
  if(TimeUtils.millis() - lastSpawnTime > 3000){
    float y = (float) (Math.random() * ( 5  - 1 ));
    setUpGroundInfinite(50 , y );
    createEnemy(51, y +  3);
  }
}

private void createEnemy(float positionX, float positionY) {
  Enemy enemy = new Enemy(WorldUtils.createEnemy(world,  positionX,  positionY));
  enemies.add(enemy);
  addActor(enemy);
  lastSpawnTime = TimeUtils.millis();
}
```

If you see any other way to optimize my game, I'd like to know them!